# UIPickerView and UITableView subview: problem with scroll after new data given

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll, uipickerview

I need assistance. I made a UIPickerView that has a UITableview subview. I iterate over the pickerArray to generate data for the table. As one chooses the component the tableArray changes. Everything works fine except the scroll. If you scroll down and then select another component the tableArray changes but the position you chose remains static. So, if you scroll to the middle of the table and then select another component you will be looking at the new table data from the middle as well. I want the table to scroll back to the top of the table and not stay at the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your table view, call:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: You are right, sorry for not following directions. Thank you.

Comment: No, it didn't work. I have tried this before. I put in the cellForRowAtIndex, is that the problem? Am I putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: I have also tried: [pickTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
                                                            [pickTable scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1,1) animated:YES];


    BOOL scrollsToTop;

    pickTable.scrollsToTop = YES;

Comment: cellForRowAtIndex is the wrong place. Put it in the method that executes when you select a component.

Comment: There you go. Thank you so much. I am forever putting methods in the wrong place. Thank you!!!

Comment: I would have never thought to put that scroll method in the didSelectRow in Component instance method.

Comment: I am getting an error message and the app is crashing: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

Comment: Are you calling that on the correct UITableView? It seems you are calling it on a table that does not have a single row.

Comment: The only place the the scrollToRowAtIndex worked before sending an error message was in the didSelectRow in component. I have put this method everywhere. Does it need its own instance method?

Comment: The number of rows change depending on the components one selects.

Comment: I found one that doesn't crash in the didSelectRow in Component. [self.Table scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];

Comment: Thank you so much Akshay. I really appreciate your help and I have been trying to figure this problem out all day.